# Use of 'e pluribus' as an adjective and meaning?

Tags: latin

I came across a sentence that uses 'e pluribus' as an adjective. I can't give the exact sentence, but it's something like 'They have many e pluribus quizzes'. Is this commonplace, and what is its meaning? Thank you!

Comment: Doesn’t seem like a proper usage to me.

Comment: Unless the quizzes have an 'e pluribus' theme in common. Which I doubt.

Comment: Can you find samples using *e pluribus* as an adjective anywhere else? Right now it sounds like an error - I don't know what "They have many *out of many* quizzes" would mean.